# 2 div are coming horizontally in same in all except IE6? how to solve?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

2 divs are coming horizontally in same in all except IE6? but in IE 6 second `div` is falling under first div. both `div` has fixed width and `float:left`

this is code of container div

```
#home2colContainer {margin-top:40px;overflow:hidden;width:1000px;}
```

this is for first div

```
#home2colLeftColContainer {float:left;margin-left:20px;width:675px;}
```

and this is for second div

```
#home2colRightColContainer {float:left;margin-left:30px;margin-top:9px;width:268px;}
```

Comment: Post the CSS code/HTML code for these DIVs? Are there any padding/margins applied to the DIVs?

Comment: And how wide does #home2colContainer render? From what I see above it'll need to be at least 993 px width... is it? Also, the contents of these columns, does this also fit within the 675px/268px respectively?

Comment: #home2colContaine is taking width:1000px

Comment: @balusC - why you removed your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try absolutely positioning the second one horizontally, and absolutely relative to the first vertical.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are dealing with the double margin bug ( http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html ) ..

Add `display: inline;` to your `home2colLeftColContainer` and it should work..

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved

I added `_display:inline` to `#home2colLeftColContainer`

```
#home2colLeftColContainer {float: left; margin-left: 20px; width: 675px;_display:inline}
```

and `_margin-left: 15px` to `#home2colRightColContainer`

```
#home2colRightColContainer {margin-top: 9px; float: left; margin-left: 30px; _margin-left: 15px; width: 268px}
```