# Why does the XHTML 1.1 doctype trigger quirks mode?

Tags: cross-browser, doctype, dtd, quirks-mode, xhtml-1.1

I'm not using the XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`

I'm only using this DTD as a first thing in a page? [which has no problem rendering in strict mode.](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=2&cid=e2f258c46d285fee)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

It validated as quirks mode with this site http://vesa.piittinen.name/doctype/

(I can't give the link to the site on which I'm working)

In IE 6 it shows **almost standards mode**, and in FF it shows **full standards mode**.

Should I change my doctype to get the same rendering in all browser?

[I'm having a rendering problem in a site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139331/2-div-are-coming-horizontally-in-same-in-all-except-ie6-how-to-solve)

Comment: Well if IE6 is an issue for you the moral of the store here is actually don't use XHTML. Use HTML 4.

Comment: IE6 doesn't have an Almost Standards Mode, as far as it's concerned.

Comment: @David Kolar - then how render IE6 with w3c box model to get consistency in all browser

Comment: That isn't actually a problem (see my answer below), but writing HTML compatible XHTML is usually not worth the effort, and the state of various standards means that the compliance of serving 1.1 as text/html is dubious, so I would stick with HTML 4.01 Strict anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your doctype is fine..

The problem lies with a specific bug (IE6 double margin on floated elements) you are dealing in your other post.. See there for an answer to the problem ..

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation on that site:

> Internet Explorer 7 and 6 don't have a real non-quirks mode, it is similar to the limited quirks mode of the other browsers. IE 5.5 and before only have a quirks mode.

It is because the author is letting his dislike of Internet Explorer stop him from using the accepted terminology for the rendering modes of that browser. IE6 Standards/Strict Mode isn't "good enough" so he calls it "Limited Quirks Mode"

Answer (score -1):

Check here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html[1](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) - this is the right link.

Check the Compatibility Master Table. Do you HAVE to make it work for IE6? I would suggest trying to convince the client that IE6 is not a browser to use.

Aside from that, use 4.01 Strict and make sure you validate you pages.

Comment: That table says nothing about how to trigger quirks / standards modes.